# How to best pause and resume a surfaceView thread

Tags: android, multithreading

My thread is not stopped when onPause occurs, leading to a "thread already started" logcat error onResume as I can't have an two thread instances running. How do I terminate the thread at this point? I believe I need to do something like:

```
gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
```

But I can't add that to my balloonBasic onPause, I think the context would be wrong. So help please, the code appears below. (code examples would be REALLY helpful, thanks)

My activity:

```
public class balloonBasic extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(new GameViewBasic(this));
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SoundManager.getInstance();
    SoundManager.initSounds(this);
    SoundManager.loadSounds();
    }

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //what do I put here?
}
}
```

My surfaceview:

```
public class GameViewBasic extends SurfaceView {

...abbreviated declarations...
private static SurfaceHolder holder;
private static GameLoopThreadBasic gameLoopThread;

   public GameViewBasic(Context context) {
         super(context);
         gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThreadBasic(this);
         holder = getHolder();
         holder.addCallback(new Callback() {



                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
                {
                    gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
                }


                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                       createSprites();
                       mapspritegraphics();

                       gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                       gameLoopThread.start();

                }

                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) 
                {
                }
         });
   }
...abbreviated for brevity....
```

My thread:
    public class GameLoopThreadBasic extends Thread {
       private GameViewBasic view;
       private volatile boolean  running = false;

```
   public GameLoopThreadBasic(GameViewBasic gameViewBasic) {
         this.view = gameViewBasic;
   }
   public void setRunning(boolean run) {
         running = run;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
         long ticksPS = 25; // =(1000/fps) ie 25ticksPS = 40fps
         long startTime;
         long sleepTime;

         while (running) {
                Canvas c = null;
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                try {
                       c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                       synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                              view.onDraw(c);
                       } 

                } catch (Exception f) {} //
                finally {
                       if (c != null) {
                              view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                       }
                } 
                sleepTime = (ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
                try {
                       if (sleepTime > 0)
                              sleep(sleepTime);
                       else
                              sleep(10);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with calling gameLoopThread.setRunning(false); in your on pause?  You should stop the thread i.e. let it finish execution and save your state.

Comment: Because my onPause is in balloonBasic which would then tell me "gameLoopThread cannot be resolved" as it appears in my surfaceview  GameViewBasic. I think it is a context issue that I can't get my head around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was working on a game a while ago, and I used LunarLander as inspiration in the early stages...but it turns out that the LunarLander sample code actually has that bug (trying to start a thread that is already running)!
Below is a solution to the problem, in the class extending SurfaceView. I found the solution online somewhere, but I can't remember where because it was a long time ago.

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    if (mMyThreadName.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED)
    {
        mMyThreadName = new MyThreadName(xxx);
    }

    mSurfaceIsReady = true;
    mMyThreadName.start();
}
```

Note that I also called mMyThreadName = new MyThreadName(xxx); in the constructor of the same class extending SurfaceView. I think my surfaceDestroyed callback worked the same as the LunarLander one, ie. mSurfaceIsReady was set to false in there, among other things.

*EDIT*

[Android IllegalThreadStateException in LunarLander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683136/android-illegalthreadstateexception-in-lunarlander)

It looks like there may be a better solution than the code I posted above. Instead, it may be possible to always just instantiate the thread in surfaceCreated, without checking if it was terminated, and don't instantiate it anywhere else. I haven't tried this second method though!

I may be misunderstanding your question, if I am I'm sorry.

Comment: but this checks the thread before creating it on first run, so a null pointer exception will result. I am trying to modify this to check if null also and act accordingly, but no luck yet. If you could check your actual app it may clarify things otherwise maybe you can remember how to modify the above.

Comment: You may have missed this part that I said: "I also called mMyThreadName = new MyThreadName(xxx); in the constructor of the same class extending SurfaceView" <- That happens before the surface is created, so the check for Thread.State.TERMINATED won't be null the first time.

Comment: Admittedly it's not very elegant instantiating the thread in two different places. That's why I posted the EDIT in my original answer, which offers another possible solution which I never tried.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. I had an idea that I ran with instead. I just checked if my sprites existed already, and if they did, then don't create the thread and sprites again as well. OK, your way might be better but my way is currently working and thus now less work....You did help me to try and inspire this solution though. Thanks for your help. TICK.